# Cardinality of Two Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that two sets $(0,1)$ and $(a, \infty) $ have the same cardinality.
There are proofs all over the Internet, but I do not understand *why*. I cannot make head or tail of it. Can someone please explain details?

I know you have to show there is a bijection between the two sets, but I do not understand how to come up with a function.

My book says to define f:$(0,1)$ -> $(a, \infty)$ by f(x) = 1/x - 1 + a.
I do not know how they reached this equation.

Comment: Maybe: You know $\frac{1}{x}$ and its properties. For example $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (1, \infty)$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is a bijection. You learn that from experience. Also, you should try to prove it. And then translate the function.

Comment: By scaling $\frac{1}{x}$'s graph, you can see that $f(x) = \frac{a}{x}$ is another bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(a, \infty)$ if $a > 0$.

Comment: So the translation of -1 + a; -1 moves it down, so new function crosses the x-axis. Then + a is a shift to right, so the range starts at a.

Comment: Let the domain of $f$ be $(0,1)$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. The range of $f$ is $(1,\infty)$. Doing $-1$ makes the range $(0, \infty)$ and then doing $+ a$ makes the range $(a, \infty)$.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of a bijection, it means that there is a one-to-one mapping between the elements of two different sets, in this case $(0, 1)$ and $(a, \infty)$. So if you can pair off every single element in both sets, they must have the same amount of elements, right?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why there is arbitrary $$(a, infinity)$$ for the range of the function.

Comment: Are you questioning why a can take any value? It may help if you look up the definition for "uncountably infinite". Remember we are showing that $(0, 1)$ and $(a, \infty)$ are the "same size", we aren't trying to put a number on it.

Comment: But if the domain is $(0,1)$ then the range can only be positive for f(x) = 1/x. Then a must be positive. So this is a bijection between Reals and Positive Reals?

Comment: a can take a negative value and the function you have been given as your answer is still valid.

Would you be able to solve the problem if you were asked to show that the set $(0, 1)$ has the same cardinality as say $(0, 2)$ or $(1, 2)$? Could you find such functions?

Comment: For (0,1) and (0,2) it is defined by f(x) = 2x? And for (0,1) and (1,2) it is defined by f(x) = x + 1?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} x) + a$ where $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (a, \infty)$ is such a bijection. See a graph.

Comment: I do not understand how to do without looking at graph. My book says this f(x) = 1/x - 1 + a. How do they come up with this?

Comment: It's just worth remembering that $\tan$ is a bijection from $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ to $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and just using that.

Comment: Just verify this function is one-to-one and onto.